# tick in Programming go

Tags: go

I run following code on a tour of go website

```
package main

import "time"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := time.Tick(1 * time.Minute)
    for now := range c {
         fmt.Printf("%v\n", now)
    }
}
```

But it said 
    throw: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

```
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-25c44134_87776a49_1b5620b3_abba0ea7_70540ccf/prog.go:8 +0x53
```

Is it a problem of their side or problem in my code?

Answer (score 4):

`[WorksForMe]`

If you're running this code on golang.org it's not going to work. Its rules are a little different, and it doesn't allow this kind of sleeping. Instead install the Go compiler locally and run it on your own computer.

Also, you'll probably want to change `time.Minute` to `time.Second` so that you can see what it's actually doing without having to wait an entire minute.

Comment: In fact time is stopped on the go tour runtime. The simplest to see it is to exectute `fmt.Println(time.Now())`.